# Latex to doc file conversion

Tags: miktex, installing

Unfortunately, the package miktex-tex4ht-base-2.9 could not be installed.Please
check the log file:
C:/Users/BBC4/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/htlatex.log

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Where's this log file?